# Change scale of a div around its central pivot point

Tags: jquery, css

I was reading about jQuery's [scale effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/scale-effect/), but I can't seem to get it working.

All I want to do is scale a `div` to 90% of its original size on its central pivot point and also fade its opacity to 80% when the user hovers over, then revert it back when their mouse leaves the div.

Comment: i think it would be smoother and efficient to use CSS. especially if you want it to run smoothly on mobile.

Comment: How to do it with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using `css` :

```
#yourDiv 
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#yourDiv:hover
{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  opacity:0.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `transform` function :

```
#yourDiv 
{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1,1);
          transform: scale(1,1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#yourDiv:hover
{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  opacity:0.8;
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Heres the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/o3whjz33/5/

**Update :** As you can see `transform` is more elegant. but make sure you add browser prefixes to ensure it works fine for all.

[pleeease.io/play](http://pleeease.io/play/) - this website does a good job of automatically adding prefixes. Cheers.

**Update 2:** The `transition property can be specified for individual properties instead of all, like this:

```
 transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

you can read more about `transform` and `transition` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

for opacity on hover ypu can use `:hover`

```
#toggle {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: #000;
opacity:1;    
}
#toggle:hover {
opacity:0.8;
}


<div id="toggle"></div>
```

And to reduce width on click you can use javascript

```
$(document).click(function () {
$("#toggle").css({       
    "width": "90%",
    "margin-left":"5%"
});
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/41n8kjr9/1/)